# Javafx and fxml button not clickable

Tags: button, javafx, click, fxml, traversal

I have a mixed up codes where I am building a program using Scene Builder with Splash Screen. I built a button on a TitledPane on top of Anchor Pane which is root. I set the fx:id and when I run, I cannot click anything. Not even a tab from titled pane or any buttons. Funny thing is, I can traverse with tab key and click space to actually mouse click it. What is going on and what should I do fix this?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.util.Duration;
```

/**
 *
 * @author heecheonpark
 */
    public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private AnchorPane root;

@FXML
private TitledPane tPane;

@FXML
private AnchorPane aPane1;

@FXML
private ListView listView;

@FXML
private Button addBtn;

@FXML
private void addButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (selectedFile != null){
                listView.getItems().add(selectedFile.getName());  
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("The file is not valid.");
            }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
    if (!MajorProject.isSplashLoaded){
    loadSplashScreen();

    }
}    
private void loadSplashScreen(){
    try {
        AnchorPane aPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SplashFXML.fxml"));
        root.getChildren().addAll(aPane);
        FadeTransition fadeIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(3), aPane);
        fadeIn.setFromValue(0);
        fadeIn.setToValue(1);
        fadeIn.setCycleCount(1);

        FadeTransition fadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(3), aPane);
        fadeOut.setFromValue(1);
        fadeOut.setToValue(0);
        fadeOut.setCycleCount(1);

        fadeIn.play();

        fadeIn.setOnFinished((e) -> {
        fadeOut.play();
        MajorProject.isSplashLoaded = true;
        });

        fadeOut.setOnFinished((e) -> {
            try { 
                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        });

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="root" focusTraversable="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="majorproject.FXMLDocumentController">
   <children>
      <ListView fx:id="listView" layoutX="302.0" layoutY="53.0" prefHeight="304.0" prefWidth="248.0">
         <effect>
            <Glow />
         </effect>
      </ListView>
      <TitledPane fx:id="tPane" animated="false" mouseTransparent="true" text="Product">
         <content>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="aPane1">
               <children>
                  <Button layoutY="131.0" mnemonicParsing="true" text="Button" />
                  <Button fx:id="addBtn" layoutY="104.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addButtonAction" text="Add" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you set the property `mouseTransparent="true"` at your `TitledPane`.

In JavaFX the MouseTransparent property make any Node **and all his children** ignore any mouse interaction, that's why you can't click the buttons. Just remove it and it should work.

[Node - MouseTransparentProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#mouseTransparentProperty)